# Delete records if not present in subquery

Tags: postgresql, delete, postgresql-9.5

I want to delete records from a table that are not found in a subquery. But it's not having the desired result.

The table has multiple rows per SKU. Each price row has a `valid_from` and `valid_to` date fields. I want to erase all prices but keep those that are currently valid (where `valid_to` is greater or equal to current date). I want to maintain future prices (where `valid_from` is in the future), but one step at a time.

Here's what I tried:

```
delete from prices
    where prices.id <> (
        select distinct on (sku) prices.id
        from prices p2
            where
                p2.valid_to >= CURRENT_DATE
            and p2."type" = 'regular'
            and prices.id = p2.id
        order by sku, p2.valid_from desc, p2.inserted_at desc
    )
```

The table has around 500k rows. This subquery returns around 23k rows. I expect that my above query will delete everything but those 23k rows.

```
    select distinct on (sku) prices.id
    from prices
        where
            valid_to >= CURRENT_DATE
        and "type" = 'regular'
    order by sku, valid_from desc, inserted_at desc
```

But it's not deleting anything. Why does it not work the way I expect it to?

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."prices" ( 
    "id" Bigint DEFAULT nextval('prices_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    "type" Character Varying( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    "unit_price" Numeric( 11, 3 ) NOT NULL,
    "wholesale_price" Numeric( 11, 3 ),
    "min_wholesale_quantity" Numeric( 11, 3 ),
    "valid_from" Date NOT NULL,
    "valid_to" Date NOT NULL,
    "product_cost" Numeric( 11, 3 ) NOT NULL,
    "tax_rate" Numeric( 11, 3 ) NOT NULL,
    "store_product_id" Bigint,
    "inserted_at" Timestamp Without Time Zone NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" Timestamp Without Time Zone NOT NULL,
    "sku" Character Varying( 2044 ),
    PRIMARY KEY ( "id" ) );

CREATE INDEX "prices_store_product_id_index" ON "public"."prices" USING btree( "store_product_id" Asc NULLS Last );

CREATE INDEX "index_sku" ON "public"."prices" USING btree( "sku" Asc NULLS Last );

ALTER TABLE "public"."prices"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "prices_store_product_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ( "store_product_id" )
    REFERENCES "public"."store_products" ( "id" ) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON DELETE Cascade
    ON UPDATE No Action;
```

Comment: Inside the subquery you require " and prices.id = p2.id", outside you specify "<>".  An id can't be equal and different at the same time.

Comment: Is prices.id not unique?

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables in question adding the desired output. Those answering need a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486).

Comment: @GerardH.Pille each sku can have multiple prices, where `valid_from` and `valid_to` is in the past or future. I want to erase all prices and only leave those currently valid. I know my query will also erase future prices (those where `valid_from` is in the future), but one step at a time.

Comment: @EvanCarroll done.

Comment: @Mohamad could you throw in some sample data, and sample output.

Comment: @EvanCarroll sure. Sample output for the subquery?

Comment: Do you also want to remove all type != "regular", whatever valid_to?

Answer (score 3):

Use the "not in", and don't refer to the outer query:

```
delete from prices
where (sku,id) Not in (
    select p2.sku, p2.id
    from prices p2
        where p2.valid_to >= CURRENT_DATE
        and p2."type" = 'regular'
)
```

Comment: You're query does not include the `distinct on` clause. I'll try it, but I suspect it might work as intended.

Comment: I tried it and it is taking much too long. Around 5 minutes has passed and it's still running.

Comment: I'll add the sku, but the query may take a couple of days. Also, the "prices.id" in the subselect was an error.

Comment: You should really almost never use `NOT IN`. In most senses, it's inferior to `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @EvanCarroll postgresql is wise enough to handle this the best way

Comment: No, it's not. Just try having a `null` sku or id, duplicate prices or sku/ids, or lots of prices, or indexes on either.

Comment: It still doesn't do the same thing as the `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to copy the subquery rows to a temporary table, erase the other table, and then copy them back?

Comment: I think it'll be easier not using a subquery, but I need an answer on my comment on your question.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ What's the use of a distinct when selecting a unique id?

Comment: The id is not unique. Second, it's DISTINCT ON, not DISTINCT.

Comment: Id is the primary key, how can it not be unique?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment "I want to erase all prices and only leave those currently valid. I know my query will also erase future prices (those where valid_from is in the future), but one step at a time", here are two steps, erase only old prices:

```
delete from prices
  where p2.valid_to < CURRENT_DATE
     or p2."type" != 'regular'
```

If this is too much for a single transaction, add a test on the number of rows (limit, rownum < ...) and repeat until all old prices are gone.

Comment: That won’t work either. I think sample data would help. When I get to the office I will add some. But many prices are valid until 01-01-9999. So an SKU can have multiple valid prices separated only by their ‘valid_from’.